# Add delay before PHP echo

Tags: php

I have an echo call within a simple PHP script to print a parameter on screen:

```
<body>
<p>the string will appear in 30 seconds:</p>
<p><?php echo $string; ?></p>
</body>
```

I want that before the "echo" runs, that system will wait X seconds. hence, the text "the string will appear after 30 seconds" will appear first, and after 30 seconds, the $string will appear below it. How it can be done? the Sleep() tends to delay the whole page before loading.

Comment: Make sure your output isn't buffered.

Comment: that looks like it would be much better achieved using javascript?

Comment: Then you should use Javascript for asynchronous task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use PHP sleep to wait 30 seconds:

```
<body>
<p>the string will appear in 30 seconds:</p>
<p><?php sleep(30); echo $string; ?></p>
</body>
```

However, when you do this, depending on your PHP and Apache settings, your entire page may wait 30 seconds before fully rendering and sending an HTTP response back to the client.

Additionally, if you send a partial response to the client, it may sometimes wait to render content until enough of the page is loaded to present the data (e.g. in the case of a table).

Try using JS instead, to allow the page to render and then present the hidden data after 30 seconds:

```
<body>
<p>the string will appear in 30 seconds:</p>
<p id="sleep" style="display:none"><?php echo $string; ?></p>
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('sleep').style.display = '';
    }, 30000);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Indeed, the sleep() delay the whole page. The second method somehow didn't work, but when doing something similar using JS, the code indeed appeared after X seconds, but it was still visible in the html source which I'm trying to prevent this scenario.

Comment: You could instead use an AJAX request on a 30-second delay to retrieve the data from the server and display it on the page.  Check out https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: It didn't work because I had a timeout of 30 milliseconds.  Updated to 30000, which works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a workaround to this situation with Javascript. jQuery library is very clean and useful. You should try it:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <p>the string will appear in 30 seconds:</p>
    <p id="string" hidden="hidden"><?php echo $string; ?></p>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#string").delay(30000).show();
});
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: since Javascript is a client-side language, this solution just "delays" the $string echoing in the client device, but the variable $string is received in any case since the beggining from the server... If there was some "impatient and hacking prone" client, just viewing the source code of your page would do the trick... :(

**SERVER-SIDE ALTERNATIVE**: If the presented workaround is not valid for your application (since I do not know its security requirements), I would try, for example with an alternative server-side method check. Here are the basic steps:

1. Save the **timestamp** of the **initial request** on the server along with information of the client (e.g. in a session cookie).
2. Then, do not send the $string right from the server, just leave it empty.
3. With JS, delay 30 seconds before asking again to the server (e.g. via AJAX) for the $string. This AJAX call will then trigger 30 seconds after the initial request and the server will now be able to check the session cookie (with the information about the client and timestamp).
4. If (current_timestamp() - cookie_timestamp() >= 30) ==> the server returns $string or nothing in other case.

Good luck ;)

Comment: TNX...I have decided to do a server side solution. All JS methods Hides the string but it appears on the html source.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me
if you want to add more time change on **content** for me I added **2** second before going to read.php page

```
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;URL=read.php'/>";
```